# insert array into constructor Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function that return array of this form

```
  [1.2,1.3,2.3]
```

and I created data:

```
data SpecielNumber = SP Float Float Float
```

How Can I from the `foo` function  that returns the number to Generate `SpecielNumber` ?

something like this dont work :(

```
  x=[1.2,1.3,2.3]
  SP x
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully, these will give some clues.  You should read more...

```
> data SpecielNumber = SN Float Float Float deriving (Show)   
> let makeSN [x,y,z] = SN x y z

> makeSN [1.2,1.3,2.3]
SN 1.2 1.3 2.3
```

Comment: Oh I get it.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, `[1.2, 1.3, 2.3]` is not an array, its a list.

Second, your data type `SpecialNumber` needs a constructor name. So you can make it have a list in its constructor like this:

```
data SpecialNumber = SpecialNumber [Float]
```

The first `SpecialNumber` is the name of the type. The second is the name of the constructor. These are different name spaces. It is conventional to have the two match unless you are defining a type with different variants, like:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

The `Left` and `Right` are alternative constructors, and the type is called `Either`.

Comment: Half the answer discusses a minor aside on naming conventions. It would probably be sufficient to say "It is common for a single data constructor to have the same same as the type constructor; the two are always distinguishable by context" and leave it at that.